# Using google-maps sdk in Android App with custom Tiles from GeoServer

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geoserver

I'm trying to create an App which displays a 2D map using google-maps sdk and gets the Tiles from GeoServer, I'm having a problem regarding the server returning the different zoom-levels not as expected 1x1, 4x4, 16x16 squares, instead it uses half the Tiles in Height compared to width: 4x2, 16x8 etc...
This ends up in the map being displayed kind of ok but with half the tiles at the top being empty, is there a way to configure this and male it work with this kind of tiles?

The server uses EPSG:4326 projection.

Using an offset I was able to center the map but while zooming it doesn't behave as expected...

Here is a gif of the resulting map: https://gph.is/g/E1qQgkw

Here are some captures on the right of the tiles being returned and on the left a different layer that works as expected:

[image: Here are some captures on the right of the tiles being returned and on the left a different layer that works as expected]

Is there a way to configure google-maps to work with this projection and tiles? I'm even willing to switch to a different sdk if that's not the case...

I'll appreciate any help or pointers...

Answer (score 1):

EPSG 3857, Pseudo-Mercator is really the client "standard" for consuming tiles
https://epsg.io/3857

and I'm not aware of any other SDK capable of consuming non-standard tiles (osmdroid, mapsforge, mabox,..)

So your Geoserver instance will have to serve EPSG:3857, either on-the-fly, or pre-generated.

I couldn't understand if Geoserver is serving WMS tiles. In that case you can pass the EPSG code as parameter while requesting tiles. 
Take a look at this add-on for Google Maps, to see how it's done,
https://github.com/shalperin/android-wms

In case Geoserver is just serving a cache of pre-generated X/Y/Z tiles you'll have to regenerate that cache.

Nevertheless, here's the official demo on how to consume tiles using TileOverlay
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/TileOverlayDemoActivity.java

Comment: Thanks for your response! it helped clarify the issue. The GeoServer is not returning WMS Tiles for that satellite layer, its a pre Generated set of Tiles and sadly I have to make it work because other services already use those Tiles and we can't change them.
I'm looking into any sdk that could work with this ESPG:4326  Tiles or into how to process the tiles to generate EPSG:3857 on the fly on mobile, I was able to find some web libraries but nothing that could work on a mobile device offline.

Comment: ...the only possibility on the client-side you are left with, is going hybrid/web. Both Leaflet and Openlayers JS libraries support arbitrary projections, For example, https://github.com/idris-maps/leaflet-custom-projection

Answer (score 0):

By default, [GeoServer](https://geoserver.org) (actually the internal [GeoWebCache](https://www.geowebcache.org/)) is able to provide tiles using 3 related but distinct standards [WMTS](https://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wmts), [TMS](https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification) and [WMS-C](https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WMS_Tile_Caching) in two projections EPSG:4326 (lat/lon degrees) or EPSG:900913 (now known as EPSG 3857, Psuedo Web Mercator).

Which of those end points you need is dependent on the SDK you are using, but looking at the images you show the one on the left is in EPSG:4326 and the right is EPSG:3857.

Answer (score 0):

After much investigation we figure out the problem and come to a solution, maybe it can help someone in the future, the problem was that the Satellite tiles where in a different projection compared to the Road ones, ESPG:4326 vs ESPG:3857 (The most common one aka Web Mercator that google maps and all other sdk use)

We couldn't make any changes to the tiles but we did have the posibility to make changes to the server so [MapProxy](https://github.com/mapproxy/mapproxy) was our best option, using that tool we where able to transform 4326 to 3857 and consume the tiles from the mobile client with no changes.
it's a python program that runs on windows, and acts as a proxy between the tiles that the client request and the server providing the tiles, reprojecting and exposing them on a new endpoint.